# make Jlabel live in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent, java-2d

I have quite a similar problem to answered before in keyword in title, but I have the situation not satisfied me. In this part of code I wont to show current position of "craft". I can see it in console (function `craft.Print()`), but also want to have it in label. The label exist, but or is not "live" or in every loop is copied and fills the screen. I commented the way to make it visible only one time, but it is not pretty way to do it I think.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
int i=0;
Craft craft = new Craft();//this is object to be moved
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Timer timer;


private final int DELAY = 100;

public Board() {

    initBoard();
}

private void initBoard() {
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    timer.start();        
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    // if(craft.getX()==30&&craft.getY()==30&&i==0){
      JLabel label = new JLabel("It is, but I wont this to be live:"+craft.getX());//craft.getX() current position of the craft
       label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
       label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
       label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
       label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue);
       label.setBorder(border);
       revalidate();
       add(label);


     repaint();

     i=1;
    // }

    craft.Print();//to watch position in console
    super.paintComponent(g);

    doDrawing(g);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.drawImage(craft.getImage(), craft.getX(), craft.getY(), this); 
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.drawRect(craft.HallEntry[0],craft.HallEntry[1],
                craft.PPDX,craft.PPDY);
    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g2d.drawRect(craft.BathroomEntry[0], craft.BathroomEntry[1], 
                craft.DLX,craft.DLY);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.drawRect(craft.LivingRoomEntry[0],craft.LivingRoomEntry[1],
                craft.DSX,craft.DSY);
    g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g2d.drawRect(craft.KitchenEntry[0],craft.KitchenEntry[1],
            craft.DKX,craft.DKY);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    craft.move();
    repaint();  
}

public class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        craft.keyReleased(e);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        craft.keyPressed(e);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add components ***or*** call `repaint()` from inside one of the `paint..(Graphics)` methods!  This is not the way to achieve animation.  The easiest way to animate a GUI is to have a Swing `Timer` call repaint.  As for the label, we can always use the `Graphics` instance passed to the method and call `label.paint(graphics)` (without ever adding the label to the GUI) or simply call `drawString(..)` ..  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot-  not it works as I wont